# Need to remove headers from cURL XML response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

There's a few threads about this, but I couldn't find a solution to this issue in them. I hope it doesn't violate duplicate rules.

I've tested the following code with static XML and it works great, but said XML did not contain any headers.

I'm trying to remove headers through code after making a POST request so I can continue to process the resulting XML, but I'm not having any luck with it.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResult><auto xmlns=""><operacion>1555843</operacion><statusSuccess>TRUE</statusSuccess><statusText></statusText><cotizacion><cobertura><codigo>A0</codigo><descripcion>RESPONSABILIDAD CIVIL SOLAMENTE</descripcion><premio>928,45</premio><cuotas>01</cuotas><impcuotas>928,45</impcuotas></cobertura></cotizacion><datos_cotiz><suma>477250</suma><uso>901</uso></datos_cotiz></auto></AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResult></AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

this is the code:

```
//converting raw cURL response to XML
$temp1 = htmlspecialchars ($reply); 
//replacing top headers
$temp2 = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResult>', "<<<'EOD'", $temp1);
//replacing closing header tags     
$temp3 = str_replace('</AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResult></AUTOS_Cotizar_PHPResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>', "EOD;", $temp2);
//this returns the original $temp1 without having anything replaced
echo $temp3;

//simplexml conversion
$xml = simplexml_load_string($temp3);

//running through the array and printing all values
if ($xml !== false) {
    foreach ($xml->cotizacion as $cotizacion) {
        foreach ($cotizacion->cobertura as $cobertura) {
            echo $cobertura->codigo;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->descripcion;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->premio;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->cuotas;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->impcuotas;
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, or maybe I'm not doing this correctly. I'm just about learning right now, so feel free to correct me in any way if you want, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have any XML samples which contain the elements your after - the sample doesn't contain anything like `codigo`.

Comment: Why is this tagged with cURL?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the XML code, I mistakenly pasted an incomplete response. Also, tagged this with cURL because that's what I'm using to communicate with the web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are processing the response string is a bad idea, you should stick to processing the content as XML and work with it.  This uses XPath to find a start point to process the data (which I can't test with the current sample), but should help with what you need to do...

```
// Load the original reply
$xml = simplexml_load_string($reply);

//running through the array and printing all values
if ($xml !== false) {
    // Find the <auto> element (use [0] as you want the first one)
    $auto = $xml->xpath("//auto")[0];

    // Loop through the cotizacion elements in the auto element
    foreach ($auto->cotizacion as $cotizacion) {
        foreach ($cotizacion->cobertura as $cobertura) {
            echo $cobertura->codigo;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->descripcion;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->premio;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->cuotas;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $cobertura->impcuotas;
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP response is still an XML document, so work with it instead of fighting it. Treating it as a string is definitely not great.

As far as I can tell you're trying to work with all the `<cotizaction>` elements. It's simple to find elements inside an XML document. Read up on [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp).

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(htmlspecialchars($reply));
if ($xml) {
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cotizacion') as $cotizacion) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! xpath works perfectly, and it's going to be very useful moving forward too.